# Use the existing zookeeper in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I started the zookeeper service in standalone mode, the zookeeper binary is carried along with Kafka. Here are the contents of `zookeeper.properties`

```
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper                     
clientPort=2181                                     
maxClientCnxns=0
```

I started zookeeper using the following command.

```
kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Now zookeeper is up and running, so I don't want hbase to start its own zookeeper service. I set the following properties in `hbase-env.sh`:

```
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

Also, here are the contents of `hbase-site.xml`.

```
<configuration>              
  <property>                 
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>                             
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8030/hbase</value>             
  </property>                
</configuration>
```

I tried to start hbase using `start-hbase.sh`, and got the log from `/usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-root-master-vultr.guest.out`

```
Could not start ZK at requested port of 2181.  ZK was started at port: 2182.  Aborting as clients (e.g. shell) will not be able to find this ZK quorum.
```

It seemed that hbase was still trying to start its own zookeeper, how to prevent it from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to run HBase in pseudo-distributed mode. In such case, hbase.cluster.distributed should be set to true and your zookeeper quorum details should be provided in hbase-site.xml as mentioned in the [Apache doc](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/standalone_dist.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using the  ZK used by HBase for Kafka solved the issue for me. Configure the $HBASE_HOME/conf/hbase-site.xml  as follows and start the HBase server. Thereafter start only the kafka server.

**hbase-site.xml configuration**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>/tmp/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/tmp/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```